# calculate effort in sprint on specific dates

Tags: reporting-services, tfs, ssrs-2012

I am using TFS 2012. I am using TFS reporting (SSRS) to prepare scope creep report. My requirement is to display 4 columns(data) in chart for each sprint:

1. How many effort was planned on first day of sprint?
2. Any effort added between second day and last day of sprint?
3. Any effort removed between second day and last day of sprint
4. How many efforts were completed in sprint.

I am taking reference of "[Velocity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff731575.aspx)" report 
The "Velocity" report definitely solve 4th requirement but I am struggling to resolve all requirement in single report. I am not very much aware of MDX queries and don't know what to add or modify in existing dataset of "Velocity" report to get desired result. I am struggling to extract specific dates of sprint and use them to calculate effort on these dates.
How can I do it?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TFS API to run an "as of" query in WIQL to get the data that you want. That is how both the burn down and velocity charts are built in the web UI.

Comment: I guess, I have to use C# application to execute these WIQL. Is it not possible to create this report using SSRs which satisfy my requirements?

Comment: You mean MDX and SQL. SSRS is not a query but a display system. Yes you can query the tfs_warehouse in SQL or the Cube in MDX.

Comment: If you are sprinting then there is no Scope Creep! There is only forecasts that are not met. Not a big deal of you have the business in charge of ordering the backlog.

Comment: Yes MrHinish, I mean MDX and SQL. I'll try to use WIQL as it doesn't seem possible to do it through MDX. I agree that there is no chance of scope creep in scrum but it should be possible to display chart with effort (story point) planned on first day of sprint and is there any effort added or removed during the sprint.

Comment: Why does the PO not know? It's their backlog, they are accountable and responsible for knowing what is in there and what the team is working on. Go ask then PO!